# Kotlin Foreach loop isn't updating width

Tags: foreach, kotlin

New to Kotlin, working on a simple chain of circles. I have been able to get two circles to connect the way I want but can seem to grow the chain further. Seems like the width (w2) doesn't get updated after the first iteration. Let me know why my code isn't working and how I can improve it. 
Thank you in advance :) Stay woke!

```
val iterator = (0..12).iterator()
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(w.toFloat(), h.toFloat(), (100).toFloat(),brush1)
                iterator.next()
            }
            iterator.forEach {
                val w2 = w-100
                canvas.drawCircle((w2).toFloat(), h.toFloat(), (100).toFloat(),brush1)


            }
```

here is the kind of effect I'm looking to create

---

Comment: It seems to me that you're making complicated something that could be done with a simple for loop

Comment: the initial for loop I was working with was this:
`for (f in 0..20)
                canvas.drawCircle(((width/2).toFloat()) + 10, (height/2).toFloat(), (f * 30).toFloat(),brush1)`

and it was making concentric circles, which isn't what I was doing for

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want but I'm sur this loop is simpler. If you don't get the result that you want then your calculations are wrong. This is what you must fix

Answer (score 2):

`w2` will never change because it's based on `w` which is never modified.

You can use parameter provided to lambda (`it`) which tells you what iteration you're on, and not use weird iterator:

```
val x = 100 // starting x
val inc = 100 // offset for following circles
repeat(12){
    val targetX = x + inc * it
    canvas.drawCircle(targetX.toFloat(), y.toFloat(), 100.toFloat(), brush)
}
```

Comment: Thank You, that gave me the desired pattern :) Got any suggestions on how I can center set pattern in the middle of the screen. For this reason was initially why I was using `val w = getWidth()`